# How to chose the most recent date and last row of table in google sheet query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet, gspread

I would like to ask help to use Query functions to choose the most recent date and last row of table within this date.  I tried to use  use both "limit 1 and offset 1" in my Query clause, But It will make "Lucy" disappear from the result.

I want a little modification that:

If there is only 1 row of values within this date.  Choose this only one.

If there are multiple rows of values,  Choose the most recent dates of values.  then choose the last row of values within this date.

Since my data is huge, I prefer to use Query function to keep my data flexible. Thank you for helping. I appreciated a lot

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uBuOe-aWtsAkYJ7OSM0hE9pq5XNll9v6WoUz9s4blFg/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're Ok with changing column order, you can use this formula that uses UNIQUE to retrieve the names and XLOOKUP to find last values of each name. You can wrap it in CHOOSECOLS to change the order:

```
=LET(na,UNIQUE(B:B),{na,BYROW(na,LAMBDA(n,XLOOKUP(n,B:B,{A:A,C:C,D:D},,0,-1)))})
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I built a system using Query function.  I tried to use Query OFFSET 1, It works very well to skip the 1 Row of values.  But it will make "Lucy" disappear  from the output.    Could you help ?

Comment: You could try with LABEL inside QUERY and label each column as ''